# Getting intersection of circles using shapely?

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, within

I have a List of Points which I transform to circles. Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574897/plotting-disconnected-entities-with-shapely-descartes-and-matplotlib)

```
circles = [Point(random.random(), random.random()).buffer(random.random() * 0.1) for i in range(3)]
```

I want to know which circles within this List intersect each other. Is there a way to achieve that with a native shapely function, or do I have to iterate over the all possible combinations?

Comment: By definition a Point has zero area and zero length, therefore no intersection : [Shapely: points](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#points)

Comment: @gene as you can see, there is a buffer around the points - so an intersection should be possible! I have written a function which does what I want, but i wonder if there is a native way in shapely to do that.

Comment: You can intersect the buffers, but not the Points

Comment: @gene but when I create points like this, the buffers are stored within `circles`?! I edit the question.

Comment: with `unary_union`      look at [How to find the intersection areas of overlapping buffer zones in single shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/187499/2581)

Comment: @gene edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

The native shapely function is `unary_union` ([Planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph))

The circles

[image]

1) Using the script of [How to find the intersection areas of overlapping buffer zones in single shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187402/how-to-find-the-intersection-areas-of-overlapping-buffer-zones-in-single-shapefi/187499#187499)

```
rings = [LineString(pol.exterior.coords) for pol in circles]
union = unary_union(rings)
result = [geom for geom in polygonize(union)]
```

Result: you have all the intersections

[image]

2) You can also use other solutions according to the position of an element in a list (look at [Shapely/ Python looping through a number of polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116191/2581) 
with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html))

```
import itertools
for  i,j in itertools.combinations(enumerate(circles), 2):
    if i[1].intersects(j[1]):
        print "polygons", i[0],j[0] 
polygons 0 1
polygons 1 2

for  i,j in itertools.permutations(enumerate(circles), 2):
    if i[1].intersects(j[1]):
        print "polygons", i[0],j[0]

polygons 0 1
polygons 1 0
polygons 1 2
polygons 2 1
```

3) you can use a spatial index as [rtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) (look at [Faster way of polygon intersection with shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804366/835653))

```
 from rtree import index
 idx = index.Index()
 # create the spatial index
 for pos, cell in enumerate(circles):
    idx.insert(pos, cell.bounds)
 # loop through each polygon
 for poly in circles:
    # Merge cells that have overlapping bounding boxes
    merged_cells = unary_union([circles[pos] for pos in idx.intersection(poly.bounds)])
    # Do actual intersection
    poly.intersection(merged_cells)
```

[image]

(the two intersections here)