# Detecting overlapping blobs in image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have read the following two posts related to my question; however, my problem is slightly different and I'm having a hard time solving it.

1. [Finding if two polygons Intersect in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90055)
2. [Getting intersection of circles using shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190495)

I have an image with irregular shapes such as these: [image]

Now, with this image, I'd like to be able to identify the separate blobs, even if they're adjoined. In particular, I want to count individual blobs that are tightly overlapping. Like for instance: [image]
For instance, in that image, I want to be able to count 7 separate blobs. However, edge detection only counts 1. If I use some solidity cutoff (area of blob/area of convex hull), I'm able to count 2.

I'm not so concerned about the separate non-overlapping ones. But I'm having a really hard time detecting them using edge detection.  I tried using Opencv's Canny function and HoughesCircles function. Neither of them proved effective.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Have you been able to create the circles (from your image) that you wish to test for overlap yet?  If not, then I think the Q&As that you have looked at are only relevant to your next step.  I think your question here needs to start with "how to create circles from non-overlapping blobs?", then "how to create circles from overlapping blobs?"

Comment: I'd think that a distance calculation with local maxima would get you 18-19 of the 20, but the tightly overlapped v. ellipse and edge case calculations would take some time to evaluate. The fact that this question encompasses both vector and raster and an NP-complete problem (computer vision) makes it extremely broad for our Focused Q&A format. If you can take out the raster to vector component,  and the simple circles which are easily detected, and focus on the tightly overlapping figure problem in vector space, you'd likely get a better answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not sure I understand. Can you please elaborate? What I've understood is the following. You're asking if I can create those blobs?
No, I cannot create those blobs. I receive those images as such.

Comment: Hello Vince, I understand the difference between vector(composed of lines,paths) and raster(composed of pixels), but I don't quite understand how you deduced that this image requires vector, raster, and an NP complete problem. I'm more of software engineering background. So, if you could explain further what you meant, for knowledge sake, that'd be very helpful. How would I take out the raster to vector component? And as you suggested, I'm only after how to detect the tightly overlapping figures. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Vince I can read the image as a matrix as it is originally in tif format. Then, I can convert that matrix to a vector in matlab, if that helps. I'm just not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I am not asking if you can create those raster blobs. I am asking how far you have progressed in recognizing isolated raster blobs as vector circles before trying to recognize overlapping vector circles in raster blobs that touch.

Comment: @PolyGeo Now I understand. Yes, I'm able to detect all isolated shapes with 100% accuracy. I use the findcountour function in python, and given the color contrast, it does a great job of detecting every isolated raster blob and returns array of arrays(contours).

Comment: You need an algorithm that detect "V shapes" (2 for each overlapping and equivalent a "neck ") in each group of blobs (slope abruptly changes direction in that singular points). In above example, there are 12 "V" shapes, so number of individual overlapped blobs is 12 "V" shapes /2 +1 = 7. For an isolated blob: 0 "V" shapes/2 + 1 = 1. For group of 3 overlapped blobs: 4 "V" shapes/2+ 1 = 3 and so on. You need to analyze mathematically for that your array of arrays (contours).

Comment: @Vince If you could also post your partial solution of using distance calculation with local maxima, that'd be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware you already found the solution, so this is just for future reader (if any) who might be interested in. (As this can also be seen as an image processing).

In bio and medical area, ImageJ is well-know for such a task. Not frequently, but there are some discussions in this forum with subjects related to remote sensing.

Using ImageJ workflow would be;

1. Download and install [ImageJ](http://imagej.net/Welcome).
2. Load your image file (drag and drop the image to ImageJ menu bar).
3. Make it binary (0,1) image `Process | Binary | Make Binary`
4. Break-apart (isolate) fused particles. `Process | Binary | Watershed`.
5. Count particles by `Analyze | Analyze Particles`.(minimum size~ 500 pixels)
6. AS the process (3) flips black/white, you may want to reverse the B/W back to original by `Edit | Invert`.

[image]

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you. Sorry I could not add images yesterday for some reason. With this image I just wanted to show you (4) how `Watershed` works, (5) where to put minimum 500 pixel size, and (6) the output (it counted 20 particles).

Answer (score 3):

I tried out an algorithm based in azimuths and second derivatives, by using contours circulars, and it works well. PyQGIS code is as follows:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feat = layer.getFeatures().next()

points = feat.geometry().asPolyline()

azimuths = [ points[i].azimuth(points[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1) ]

az_diff = [ azimuths[i+1] - azimuths[i] for i in range(len(azimuths)-1) ]

sum = 0

for item in az_diff:
    if item < 0:
        sum += 1

blobs_number = sum/2 + 1

print 'blobs_number: ', blobs_number
```

For one circular "blob":

[image]

For two overlapped "blobs":

[image]

For seven overlapped "blobs":

[image]

Results were as expected.

Comment: Amazing solution. I'm still trying to test it and understand it. Is it possible to run this on just python/matlab?

Comment: Yes. You only need arrays of points. However, I used perfectly circular lines with points regularly spaced and it was relatively easy to have a condition for my **if** code. In your case, you probably will have "noise" in your data because blobs are not perfectly circular. So, you need to do an exploratory analysis for finding out the threshold corresponding to big changes in slope for your **if** code condition.